# Get geolocation by Javascript save to txt (Java/PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, geolocation

Just trying to save the geolocation and IP address to a php file  I saws this code, but it doesnt save any info to the pho file

Index.html

```
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }else{
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
function showPosition(pos){
    $.post('saver.php',{'lat':pos.coords.latitude,'lng':pos.coords.longitude},function(res){
      console.log(res);
   });
}
</script>
```

saver.php

```
<html>
<script>
<?php
   print_r($_POST);
   $a = fopen("save.txt", "a");
   fwrite($a,"Location: $_POST[lat],$_POST[lng]");
   fclose($a);
?>
</script>
</html>
```

After running the html and clicking allow to get my location.  It saves to save.txt, but the result is only.

```
Location: ,Location: ,
```

Any idea on what to edit to research.  Also would like it to save the IP address as well.

Thank you
-Noob

Comment: `saver.php` doesnot need any of that HTML its just being called like a subroutine library

Comment: What did this show you `print_r($_POST);`

Comment: No Idea I just found the code online.  I have no idea.  Im just want to save the ip, geolocation lat/long to a txt file of vistors to the site in the save.txt

Comment: Copying code off the net is fine, but you have to then read it and most importantly UNDERSTAND IT or you could be copying a happy little hack

Comment: Yea Im not a coder at all LOL.  Just want to have the lat/long and IP saved to a txt file.  It's driving me crazy as I have no understanding of this lol

Answer (score 0):

the string needs to be concatenated correctly + `$_POST` keys need to be wrapped in quotes

and i would suggest adding `\n` in `fwrite` so each entry be on a new line

```
<?php
   print_r($_POST);
   $a = fopen("save.txt", "a");
   fwrite($a,"Location: " . $_POST['lat'] . ",". $_POST['lng'] . "\n");
   fclose($a);
?>
```

and index.html is missing jquery to send the post request.
here's the html with jquery file requested from cdn

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script>
window.onload=function(){
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }else{
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
}
function showPosition(pos){
    $.post('saver.php',{'lat':pos.coords.latitude,'lng':pos.coords.longitude},function(res){
      console.log(res);
   });
}
</script>
```

---

**Side Note:
"Geolocation API:This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers."** [MDN Geolocation_API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API)

Comment: Thank you I edited the saver php.  but still only shows Location: ,Location: ,   info though.

Comment: @ExMxIxLxY I have updated my answer to include jquery in the html file. i have tested it and it's working fine now